# Making my h1 stay in place when page is resized?

Tags: html, css, position

I am having trouble with a site for my CSS class. It is for a challenge that I am almost done with. I just need my h1 with a class of com to stay in place when the page resizes. Right now, it moves when the page resizes, but I need it to stay in place and the text size changed so it isn't so big when the page is smaller.

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

.com {
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding-bottom: 32.5rem;
  margin-top: -30rem;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  position: sticky;
}
nav {
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: beige;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

footer a {
  color: beige;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222;
  color: beige;
  margin-bottom: -3rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

header {
  color: #36a;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#contactUs a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

#resources a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

#results {
  float: left;
  max-width: 27%;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem 0.2rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  flex: 1;
}
#partners {
  float: left;
  max-width: 27%;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem 0.2rem 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  flex: 1;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

#future {
  float: left;
  max-width: 27%;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem 0.2rem 1.5rem;
  border-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  }
  .com {
    padding-bottom: 32.5rem;
    margin-top: -30rem;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #results {
    margin-top: 0rem;
  }
  #partners {
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }
  #future {
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }
}

#copyright {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-left: 3.5rem;
}

#resources {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 16rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
}

#contactUs {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 43rem;
}

.row2:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #resources {
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }
  #contactUs {
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
  }
  #copyright {
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ComPack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/challenge.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amiri&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
      <img src="images/06926FRH.jpg" alt="">
      <h1 class="com">ComPack</h1>
  </header>

   <nav>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">Solutions</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Locations</a>
     <a href="#">Support</a>
   </nav>

   <section class="row">
       <article id="results">
           <h2>Results</h2>
           <p>Unde quae quidem earum, at, ullam officiis minus! Facilis incidunt impedit cum unde quae, neque debitis reiciendis perspiciatis asperiores dolor totam culpa, soluta sapiente veritatis. Accusantium illum quisquam, repellendus temporibus!</p>
       </article>

       <article id="partners">
           <h2>Partners</h2>
           <p>Adipisci soluta, voluptas perferendis illo, quas culpa doloribus? Nulla quibusdam, eveniet consectetur enim voluptatibus nam quos minus, aliquam voluptatum quis. Velit nesciunt quam, quidem praesentium laudantium nostrum nobis iusto animi.</p>
       </article>

       <article id="future">
           <h2>Future</h2>
           <p>Nam recusandae nihil harum animi excepturi nulla qui laborum sed illo repudiandae numquam quibusdam eaque, eius culpa unde pariatur suscipit inventore quos iure saepe at dolor fuga ea. Aperiam, ex.</p>
       </article>
   </section>
   <footer class="row2">
      <div id="copyright">
       <p><small>Copyright &copy; 2017 ComPack, Inc.</small></p>
       </div>

       <div id="contactUs">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Technical Support</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="resources">
          <h3>Resources</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cumque amet aspernatur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aut perspiciatis consequuntur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accusantium nihil illum</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean exactly by 'stay in place'. A snippet would probably help clarify things.

Comment: Agreed. Welcome, Tony. You'll need to create a really simplified example. We only need to see the specific code that has to do with the elements that matter - and a clear example of what you expect to accomplish.

Comment: I checked out the code: you can put it in a jsFiddle or a CodePen like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/buakpv39/  - I'm not sure where you're learning this stuff from, but most of these tactics are pretty old techniques - and there are much clearer and more simple techniques you can use now.

Comment: Thank you for doing that Derek! I am learning through a college class currently. And Richard, when I resize the page, the h1 moves upwards and goes off the page. I can edit the question for you if you'd like.

Comment: Your CSS is doing exactly what you've written. It's being absolutely positioned with a big negative margin. So - it's off the page. Negative margins are 99% of the time - a bad idea. Take a look at this for some other ways of thinking about it. https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/9622188fa5c49e4cca8294957c90b653 - also, consider getting some help in the css discord: https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I used some positioning to get it where I want it to be.